# Renamed JSON field

Tags: json, go

We want to rename a JSON field `value` to `v` in production. Till all our users use the new struct, we would continue to get old JSON structs into our code. So we want to handle this as well.

If you notice, `First` is the original structure, `Second` is the new structure. To handle both these structures, I have created a `MyStruct` and based on `version`, I copy the `OldValue` into `Value`

```
if m.Version <= 1 {
    m.Value = m.OldValue
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this, instead of my code.

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/igArKQwEJQ)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"
import "log"

type First struct {
    Version int `json:"version"`
    Value   int `json:"value"`
}

type Second struct {
    Version int `json:"version"`
    Value   int `json:"v"`
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Version  int `json:"version"`
    OldValue int `json:"value"`
    Value    int `json:"v"`
}

func main() {
    oldValue := []byte(`{"version":1, "value":5}`)
    newValue := []byte(`{"version":2, "v":7}`)

    var m MyStruct

    err := json.Unmarshal(newValue, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("New Struct")
    fmt.Println(m.Value)

    err = json.Unmarshal(oldValue, &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Old Struct")
    if m.Version <= 1 {
        m.Value = m.OldValue
    }
    fmt.Println(m.Value)

}
```

Comment: Implement the Marshaler interface (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) for your struct and you can marshal either `v` or `value` as you see fit.

Comment: If you're using REST, you really ought to encode versions in your REST URLs, not in the data you shovel around. That is, all the API URLs containing, say, `/v1/` as a component in their path parts must return and consume JSON which is formatted according to the "v1" rules, forever. If you need to change the data formats, introduce "v2", provide a new API endpoint implementing the new rules and gradually transition your clients. After transition, the "v1" endpoint becomes obsolete and may be removed safely.

Comment: Thanks. Here, we are not using the REST API. In this case, we are collecting data from different clients automatically using a javascript script. Technically we could also introduce REST method here, but we are not doing it now. We will consider it in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can actually do it with one unmarshaling, albeit you'll need another type:

```
type Second struct {
    Version int `json:"version"`
    Value   int `json:"v"`
}

type SecondWithOldValue struct {
    OldValue int `json:"value"`
    Second
}

type MyStruct SecondWithOldValue

func (v *MyStruct) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, (*SecondWithOldValue)(v)); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if v.Version <= 1 {
        v.Value = v.OldValue
    }
    return nil
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yII-ncxnU4.

Old answer below.

---

If you're OK with double unmarshaling, you can do it like this:

```
type Second struct {
    Version int `json:"version"`
    Value   int `json:"v"`
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Second
}

func (v *MyStruct) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v.Second); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if v.Version <= 1 {
        var oldV struct{ Value int }
        if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &oldV); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        v.Value = oldV.Value
    }
    return nil
}
```

First, unmarshal into the inner struct, check version, and if it's an old one, get the old value.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/AaULW6vJz_.

Comment: Thanks @Ainar-G. I took your approach in inserting into the same structure, and then just copying it, into the new variable if version is lower.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt to not use 3 different struct here as they are all the same really.

Modify your struct MyStruct as you have and load the `json:"value"` into a new variable as you are and part of your Unmarshal should copy the value into the Value variable if Value is not present.

However I would second Kostix's recommendation here. Your API or process that loads and saves data should try to account for versioning by the mechanism suggested. Add a v# to your URI or if you're saving the item down to disk, then perhaps save it with a version number as such and then process the inner section per struct that corresponds to the proper version:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "struct": { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here, we are not using the REST API. For REST, we use different version. However, in this case, we are collecting data from different clients automatically using js. Technically we could also introduce REST method here, but we are not doing it now. We will consider it in the future. Thanks for the tip.